# Shortcodes in custom post fields without the_content()

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode

I have created a custom post type which doesn't use `the_content()` to display anything in the front-end, just using echo's.

The user enters data into a text-area field in the plugin admin back-end, the CPT does some data manipulation and everything is output through a template file using a shortcode.

How can I get short-codes to fire when a user enters them into a CPT text-area in the backend admin. I can't see any filters being used. Also since it's an admin area text input field, php snippets won't work.

**EDIT:**

Perhaps a better question is how to implement `the_loop` properly in a custom post? My code currently;

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Article
*/
?>
<article class="article-single">
    <?php 
        echo do_shortcode('[banner]');

        ... loads of shortcodes to build up html...

        echo do_shortcode('[info]');
    ?>
</article>
```

Comment: You want to include the output of a shortcode in your template/function without using `the_content()`?

Comment: Yea, pretty much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a basic function which used `preg_match_all` and `preg_replace` to find my short-code tags and sanitize the content before building the HTML output for the template page.

In my case, only useful if you have the one short tag being used.

```
function img_strip($str)
{
    $preg = '/\[\bimg\b\](.*?)\[\/\bimg\b\]/';      
    preg_match_all($preg, $str, $matches);  

    if ($matches) {
        foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {

            $parsed = parse_url($match);

            if (empty( $parsed['scheme'])) {
                $match = '//' . ltrim($match, '/');
            }
            $replace = '<img src="' . $match . '" alt="floating-image" class="image">';
            $str = preg_replace($preg, $replace, $str, 1);
        }   
    }

return $str;
}
```

In future I will look into implementing the loop in my template with `the_content()`.

Comment: WordPress has built in functions for parsing shortcodes in content, I'm sure they would simplify things if it was more clear what you were trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`do_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) function for this.

```
echo do_shortcode( '[your-shortcode including="any" parameters="needed"]' );
```

Comment: Edited my answer for clarification.